# C: Comparison between character in string and '\0' doesn't work?

Tags: c, null, comparison, character

I make a function to count the number of characters of the first line of a string. In case the string is only one line long then it counts the number of characters until the terminating null \0. The portion with comparing the ch character to \n works as expected but I can't succeed in comparing the ch character to \0. It never meets the comparison even if I have added several \0 in the string. Any idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /*variables*/
    char* string="shit\nand\npee\0";
    int bytesRead=0;
    int bytesTemp=0;
    char ch=' ';

    /*find the number of characters before a newline or end of string*/
    while(ch!='\n') { //doesn't work with ch!='\0'
        sscanf(string+bytesRead, "%c%n", &ch, &bytesTemp);
        bytesRead+=bytesTemp;
        printf("Bytes read: %d\n", bytesRead);
        printf("Variable ch has value: %c\n", ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's the comparison with '\0' that you tried?

Comment: It's in the comment after the while. I didn't include it in the actual code to make it a bit clearer what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. I did see it, but I wondered if you had tried to && the two conditions.  I think first solution has it anyway.  You could also just use array indexes to scan along the string char by char, but I'm not sure what your overall objective is.

Comment: You can't be a programmer if that statement is logical to you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not testing the return value of `sscanf`. If it fails, `ch` will **not** be updated, so you'll get the last symbol twice, then read past the end of the string.

Try with something like:

```
if (sscanf(string+bytesRead, "%c%n", &ch, &bytesTemp) != 1)
  break;
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding that. Why would ch fail? Doesn't it get the \0 character at some point?

Comment: `ch` is a char. It can't "fail". `sscanf` will fail if it can't match your input spec. When it fails (for example: it reached the end of the string), it does not update `&ch` (or `&bytesTemp`). `ch` will never be set to `0` in this sscanf, because sscanf will fail if the first char at `string+bytesRead` is `'\0'`.

Comment: Yes but why would sscanf fail? A character can represent the whole ASCII and the '\0' is inside the ASCII table so at some point the ch is expected to have '\0'. My input spec is to read a character and '\0' is a character so I don't see the problem there.

Comment: sscanf operates on C _character strings_, not on random char arrays. C character strings are sequences of chars **terminated by 0**. `0` is the end-of-string marker for C "strings", it is not part of the string itself. If you want to just copy the bytes until 0, you don't need sscanf at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid using `sscanf` and do the following instead:

```
while((ch = *string) != '\n' && ch != '\0') {
  bytesRead++;
  printf("Bytes read: %d\n", bytesRead);
  printf("Variable ch has value: %c\n", ch);
  string++;
}
```

This stops when it sees either \n or \0.